# How can I use the original argument name in a function when using an apply function in R?

Tags: r

Whenever I use an apply function, using a dummy variable in the anonymous function results in the name of that dummy variable being used internally.  How can I use the original variable name internally to avoid complications when processing the resulting list?

Below is an example describing what I mean:

```
set.seed(314)

df <- data.frame(response = rnorm(500),
                Col1 = rnorm(500),
                Col2 = rnorm(500),
                Col3 = rnorm(500),
                Col4 = rnorm(500))

> apply(df[, 2:5], 2, function(x) lm(response ~ x, data = df))
$Col1

Call:
lm(formula = response ~ x, data = df)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x  
   0.074452     0.007713  


$Col2

Call:
lm(formula = response ~ x, data = df)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x  
    0.06889      0.07663  


$Col3

Call:
lm(formula = response ~ x, data = df)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x  
    0.07401      0.03512  


$Col4

Call:
lm(formula = response ~ x, data = df)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x  
   0.073668    -0.001059
```

I would like each linear regression above to use the names `Col1`, `Col2`, etc. instead of `x` in every single regression.  Furthermore, I am looking for a general way to use the original names in any situation (not just linear regression) when I use an apply function.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to do it in two steps as follows:

1) First run the regressions as you are doing
2) Replace the coefficient name and also the formula

```
l <- lapply(df[, 2:5], function(x) lm(response ~ x, data = df))
for (i in 1:length(l)) {
  names(l[[i]]$coefficients)[2] <- names(l)[i]
  l[[i]]$call <- gsub('x', names(l)[i], l[[i]]$call)
}
```

Resulting output is as follows:

```
$Col1

Call:
c("lm", "response ~ Col1", "df")

Coefficients:
(Intercept)         Col1  
   -0.04266     -0.07508  


$Col2

Call:
c("lm", "response ~ Col2", "df")

Coefficients:
(Intercept)         Col2  
   -0.04329      0.02403  


$Col3

Call:
c("lm", "response ~ Col3", "df")

Coefficients:
(Intercept)         Col3  
   -0.04519     -0.03300  


$Col4

Call:
c("lm", "response ~ Col4", "df")

Coefficients:
(Intercept)         Col4  
   -0.04230     -0.04506
```

Comment: Thanks, but it still has x in the formula call instead of Col1, Col2, etc.

Comment: Edited the answer to fix that too....you just need to grab the `call` field and modify it.

Comment: Thanks, but is there a way to do that automatically in every situation?  As in I want to not just manually replace x with the variable in every place it occurs, but do it automatically no matter what I'm working with.  My question was about how to do this in general.  Not just how to do it in linear regressions.